Spring Boot Flyway not running on startup
I have a spring boot application, and I've installed the Flyway dependency to run my Postgres migrations. However, when I run the application, nothing happens.
My pom.xml has the following:
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.flywaydb</groupId>
    <artifactId>flyway-core</artifactId>
    <version>10.20.0</version>
</dependency>

In my application.properties I have the following:
spring.flyway.enabled=true
spring.flyway.baseline-on-migrate=true
logging.level.org.flywaydb=DEBUG

spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/mydb
spring.datasource.username=username
spring.datasource.password=password

I have my migration sql file inside of resources/db/migration with the name of : V1__initial_migration.init with create table query inside.
And finally, the logs when I run the app is not showing anything related with flyway and in the database nothing changes:


2024-11-17T12:59:30.239Z  INFO 13224 --- [task_management] [           main] c.example.task_management.Application    : No active profile
set, falling back to 1 default profile: "default"
2024-11-17T12:59:31.094Z  INFO 13224 --- [task_management] [
main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Bootstrapping Spring
Data JPA repositories in DEFAULT mode. 2024-11-17T12:59:31.164Z  INFO
13224 --- [task_management] [           main]
.s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Finished Spring Data
repository scanning in 60 ms. Found 3 JPA repository interfaces.
2024-11-17T12:59:31.884Z  INFO 13224 --- [task_management] [
main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized
with port 8080 (http) 2024-11-17T12:59:31.904Z  INFO 13224 ---
[task_management] [           main]
o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2024-11-17T12:59:31.904Z  INFO 13224 --- [task_management] [
main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine    : Starting Servlet
engine: [Apache Tomcat/10.1.31] 2024-11-17T12:59:31.977Z  INFO 13224
--- [task_management] [           main] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring
embedded WebApplicationContext 2024-11-17T12:59:31.978Z  INFO 13224
--- [task_management] [           main] w.s.c.ServletWebServerApplicationContext : Root WebApplicationContext:
initialization completed in 1659 ms 2024-11-17T12:59:32.145Z  INFO
13224 --- [task_management] [           main]
com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Starting...
2024-11-17T12:59:32.362Z  INFO 13224 --- [task_management] [
main] com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool        : HikariPool-1 - Added
connection org.postgresql.jdbc.PgConnection@2668c286
2024-11-17T12:59:32.364Z  INFO 13224 --- [task_management] [
main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Start
completed. 2024-11-17T12:59:32.437Z  INFO 13224 --- [task_management]
[           main] o.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper  :
HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [name: default]
2024-11-17T12:59:32.502Z  INFO 13224 --- [task_management] [
main] org.hibernate.Version                    : HHH000412: Hibernate
ORM core version 6.5.3.Final 2024-11-17T12:59:32.545Z  INFO 13224 ---
[task_management] [           main]
o.h.c.internal.RegionFactoryInitiator    : HHH000026: Second-level
cache disabled 2024-11-17T12:59:32.937Z  INFO 13224 ---
[task_management] [           main]
o.s.o.j.p.SpringPersistenceUnitInfo      : No LoadTimeWeaver setup:
ignoring JPA class transformer 2024-11-17T12:59:33.914Z  INFO 13224
--- [task_management] [           main] o.h.e.t.j.p.i.JtaPlatformInitiator       : HHH000489: No JTA platform
available (set 'hibernate.transaction.jta.platform' to enable JTA
platform integration) 2024-11-17T12:59:33.917Z  INFO 13224 ---
[task_management] [           main]
j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Initialized JPA
EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2024-11-17T12:59:34.298Z  WARN 13224 --- [task_management] [
main] JpaBaseConfiguration$JpaWebConfiguration :
spring.jpa.open-in-view is enabled by default. Therefore, database
queries may be performed during view rendering. Explicitly configure
spring.jpa.open-in-view to disable this warning
2024-11-17T12:59:34.800Z  INFO 13224 --- [task_management] [
main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat started on
port 8080 (http) with context path '/' 2024-11-17T12:59:34.813Z  INFO
13224 --- [task_management] [           main]
c.example.task_management.Application    : Started Application in
5.045 seconds (process running for 5.497)


What can be causing this issue?

Google says you need FlywayMigrationStrategy bean defined.
Example:
@Configuration
public class FlywayConf {
    @Bean
    public FlywayMigrationStrategy clean(){
        return flyway -> {
            flyway.clean();
            flyway.migrate();
        };
     }
}


where is supposed to put that?

It is up to you. I suggest creating separate configuration class.

well, it didn't work :|
